# Ruby-on-Rails NoMethodError in my controller undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My ruby application is throwing an error which has appeared all of a sudden. the error thrown is NoMethodError in JobsDevsController # listing=> undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass

The part of my code that throws this error in my controller is

```
def is_authorised
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission..." unless current_user.id == @job.user_id
    end
```

My Controller

```
class JobsDevsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_jobs_dev , except: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :listing]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :listing]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:listing, :budget, :description, :photo_upload, :location, :update, :show ]

  # GET /jobs_devs
  def index
    @jobs_devs = JobsDev.all
  end

  # GET /jobs_devs/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /jobs_devs/new
  def new
    @jobs_dev = current_user.jobs_devs.build
  end

  # def listing
  #   @jobs_dev = current_user.jobs_dev
  # end

  # GET /jobs_devs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def budget
  end

  # POST /jobs_devs
  def create
    @jobs_dev = current_user.jobs_devs.build(jobs_dev_params)

    if @jobs_dev.save!
      redirect_to listing_jobs_dev_path(@jobs_dev), notice: 'Jobs dev was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /jobs_devs/1
  # def update
  #   if @jobs_dev.update(jobs_dev_params)
  #     redirect_to @jobs_dev, notice: 'Jobs dev was successfully updated.'
  #   else
  #     render :edit
  #   end
  # end

  def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @jobs_dev.update(jobs_dev_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @jobs_dev, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @jobs_dev }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @jobs_dev.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

  # DELETE /jobs_devs/1
  def destroy
    @jobs_dev.destroy
    redirect_to jobs_devs_url, notice: 'Jobs dev was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_jobs_dev
      @jobs_dev = JobsDev.find(params[:id])
    end

    def is_authorised
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission..." unless current_user.id == @jobs_dev.user_id
    end


    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def jobs_dev_params
      params.require(:jobs_dev).permit(:job_category, :job_type, :job_title, :job_description, :recurrence,
                                        :budget, images: []
      )
    end
end
```

Please can you help with this senario

Comment: Maybe it is because `:show` does not `:set_job`? See `before_action :set_job, except: [:index, :new, :create, :show]`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set_job for listing actiton

You may need to add to the listing action directly

```
@job = current_user.job
```

or the better way to add it to before action of listing action and take order into consideration

Comment: I have added as per your suggestion and updated my code above but still no luck ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `is_authorised` method is looking for `@job`, which isn't set in your controller; rather, you assign `@jobs_dev`.

Update the method to the following:

```
def is_authorised
  redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission..." unless current_user.id == @jobs_dev.user_id
end
```

I'm not sure that's sufficient, as you're skipping setting this in your `before_action`:

```
before_action :set_jobs_dev , except: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :listing]
```

It looks as if you'll need to remove `:listing` from the `except` clause there.

Try both of these things and it should work again. Let me know if you've any questions or have any issues with this :)